# Postgis storage format in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3

I have a postgis table with two geometries, a point for a lightning strike and an uncertainty  ellipse as a polygon for the lightning strike. I can easily pull each of those geometries into QGIS to plot them in separate layers, but I would like to plot both in one layer. This should be possible (and I am pretty sure I've done it before) using the geometry generator and geom_from_wkt/b. But as QGIS is  giving me a hex-encoded string i.e. a polygon looks like " 0103000020E96400000100000021000000BADCBE559(...) ", this will not work. I know I could have made a view in the database, using the st_totext to get the polygon as wkt, but I would prefer to keep the connection to the table, so how can I convert the hexstring from postgis to wkb or wkt to be fed to the geometry generator?

Using QGIS 3.26 / postgis 3.2.0

Comment: Just to clarify: PostGIS geometry encoding *is not* WKB.

Comment: Thanks, then I misunderstood. The text is corrected.